# MVC4 Razor - Trying to get id in url for a blog post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

All Im trying to do is get my url to have the blogid appending to it much like the following...

`http://localhost/blog/blogpost/17`

Here is my Controller...

```
    public ActionResult BlogList(){ return View(_repository); }


    public ActionResult BlogPost(string id)
    {
        ViewData["id"] = id;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {              

            return RedirectToAction("BlogPost", new { id = id });

        }
        return View(_repository);
    }
```

Now here is my route.config maproute

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "MyBlog", // Route name
            "blog/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "blogpost", id = 
               UrlParameter.Optional   } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now I can get the url to appear when I click on a blog in the blogList. The page doesn't display the blog it displays a redirect loop message. If I omit the following code ...

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {              

            return RedirectToAction("BlogPost", new { id = id });

        }
```

then I can display the blog. The url wont have the id value. Like this...

`http://localhost/blog/blogpost/`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can anyone help with this? I am absolutely lost with this. People keep giving me answer to something else and I just dont understand why. Can anyone give me detailed information or explanation to why I cant append an ID to my URL like above. Ive been told to remove BlogList which I can't do because it is in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work with your route:

```
// http://localhost/blog/bloglist
public ActionResult BlogList()
{
  return View(_repository); // show all blog posts
}

// http://localhost/blog/blogpost/1
public ActionResult BlogPost(int? id = null)
{
  if (id.HasValue == false || id.Value < 1)
  {
     // redirect to 404 page or BlogList
     throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
  var blogPostObj = _repository.Find(id.Value);
  if (blogPostObj == null)
  {
    // again redirect to 404
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
  return View(blogPostObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `BlogList()` which takes 0 parameter

```
 public ActionResult BlogList(){ return View(_repository); }
```

This is not required, since your id is type of `string` which can be null

The below code can be help you

```
public ActionResult BlogPost(string id)
 {
    var model=new ModelObject();
    if(id!=null)
    {
     var model=Blogs.Find(id); //find it from repo
     return View(model);

    }
    return View(model);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it does not look like the id field is optional.  Therefore I would change the route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "MyBlog", // Route name
        "blog/blogpost/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "blogpost" },
        new { id = @"(\d)+"} //ensures value is numeric. 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RouteData.Values["id"] + Request.Url.Query
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.